# why jquery doesnt return the success

Tags: jquery

my jquery is not populating the div myPrint on either success or failure.

here is my ajax

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'file.php',
            data: 'tyID=' + tyID.value ,
            success: function(success) {
                if(success == 1) {
                    $("#myPrint").html('Worked'); 

                } else {
                    $("#myPrint").html('there Didnt work'); 
                }
            }
        });
```

in php I have success = 0 on failure and 1 on success. I can see php working fine

here is html

```
<div id="myPrint"></div>
```

Comment: `url: file.php'` should be `url: 'file.php'`

Comment: Try adding `console.log(success)` in your success handler, and check that you're getting the output you expect.

Comment: Please show your PHP file, at least the part that produces the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'file.php',
            data: {tyID: tyID.value },
            success: function(success) {
                if(success == 1) {
                    $("#myPrint").html('Worked'); 

                } else {
                    $("#myPrint").html('there Didnt work'); 
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Nifty, but unnecessary.  the data parameter can be a string as he has done.

Answer (score 1):

My guess:

Your PHP file has to **output** 1 or 0. It is not enough to just set `$success` to 1 or 0.

In the callback, you should also use [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) to convert the return value to an integer:

```
success = parseInt(success, 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not be calling $.ajax(...), but rather $.get(...) or $.post(...). And data needs to be a map, such as {'tyID': tyID.value}.

Comment: $.get() and $.post() are short hand ways of writing the more verbose $.ajax() with the proper type specified.  So this wouldn't be the cause of his issue.